# ModelForm not getting saved on server

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a view that uses a modelform to create circles. This works perfectly fine on localhost but on server, the data is not getting created since "save" method is not working.

```
ModelForm:
class CircleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Circles
        fields = ('heading','description',)
        #exclude = ['current_status', 'progress', 'Owner', 'team_tag', 'exceptional_tag','Team']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CircleForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for name, field in self.fields.items():
            if field.widget.attrs.has_key('class'):
                field.widget.attrs['class'] += ' text'
            else:
                field.widget.attrs.update({'class':'text'})

Model:
class Circles(CommonInfo):
    CURRENT_STATUS = (('P', 'pending'),
                        ('C', 'complete'),
                        ('ED', 'exceeded deadline'),
                        ('I', 'incomplete'))
    Owner = models.ForeignKey(OrganisationUser, related_name="owner_name", blank=True, null=True)
    Team = models.TextField(default='', blank=True, null=True)
    heading = models.CharField(default='', max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(default='', max_length=250)
    progress = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    deadline = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    current_status = models.CharField(choices=CURRENT_STATUS, max_length=2, default='P')
    team_tag = models.ForeignKey("certificates.Tag", related_name="team_tag_given", blank=True, null=True)
    exceptional_tag = models.ForeignKey("certificates.Tag", related_name="exeptioml_tag_given", blank=True, null= True)

View:
def non_ajax_post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        circle_form = CircleForm(request.POST)

        if circle_form.is_valid():
            try:
                circle = circle_form.save(commit=False)
                circle.Owner = request.user.organisation_user
                #circle.Team = json.dumps(request.POST.get('hidemps_id'))
                team_tag = Tag.objects.get(pk = request.POST.get('team_tag_id'))
                exceptional_tag = Tag.objects.get(pk = request.POST.get('exceptional_tag_id'))
                circle.team_tag = team_tag
                circle.exceptional_tag = exceptional_tag
                deadline = string_time_to_datetime(request.POST.get('deadline'), type_of_date='m/d/y')
                if deadline < datetime.now():
                    request.session['deadline_error'] = True
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
                circle.deadline = deadline
                circle.save()
                request.session['circle_saved'] = True
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path) #here a different context is sent on page load
            except Exception as e:
                print e.message
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```

This code works the way I want it and creates a circle. But this happens when I perform this on localhost. When I try it on the server, it doesn't work.
The problem lies in the line "circle.save()"
I used multiple print statements to find out the problem. The printing stops when it encounters "circle.save()" line. After that it redirects me to the same page.

Can anyone suggest some solutions?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: I have many, many suggestions, but here's one absolute must: drop that `except` clause. Django prints error messages for you in debug, or logs them otherwise: all you're doing here is swallowing them.

Comment: It doesn't throw any error. All it does is simply reload the page.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to put my code in try, and without except it wont work. I have added a logger also to print the error in except. but that also won't show anything.

Comment: But that's my point, take out the try/except. It serves no purpose except to hide the very errors you're trying to debug.

Comment: Ok, I'll remove that. How is it that it is working on localhost and not on the actual server.?

Comment: Thank you @DanielRoseman.. After removing try/except I was able to find the error.. there was an extra field in the model which was not removed on the server's code. Now, my code is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Also, you can try to use sys.exc_info() to get the your exception traceback. May be there is a wrong sequence position in your database on the server?